# Implementation of the change making algorithm

Tags: python, unit-testing, change-making-problem

I wrote a set of python classes for solving the change making problem, in various forms.

> Given the coin denominations and values:
>
> - Find all possible ways of making change.
> - Find a best way of making change (minimize number of coins).
> - Determine whether it is possible to make change.

This version of the project on [github](https://github.com/jishi9/coin-change/tree/d4e14ef1e70ee68718dcdafe262ed57ee0293883).

---

## Main file: [change.py](https://github.com/jishi9/coin-change/blob/d4e14ef1e70ee68718dcdafe262ed57ee0293883/change.py)

```
# An implementation solving the change making problem and related problems.
# See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

from itertools import takewhile

def abstractMethod(): raise NotImplementedError('Abstract method')

class CoinChanger(object):
    def __init__(self, denominations):
        CoinChanger.verify_denominations(denominations)
        self.denominations = tuple(sorted(denominations))
        self.cache = dict()

    @staticmethod
    def verify_denominations(denominations):
        assert len(set(denominations)) == len(denominations)
        assert all(type(d) == int for d in denominations)
        assert all(d > 0 for d in denominations)

    def change_for(self, amount):
        if amount not in self.cache:
            self.cache[amount] = self._value_to_store_for_amount(self._change_for(amount))

        for change in self.cache[amount]:
            yield change

    def _change_for(self, amount):
        if amount == 0:
            yield self._get_value_for_zero_change()
            return

        for i, d in self.denominations_less_than_or_equal_to(amount):
            remaining_amount = amount - d
            for change in self.change_for(remaining_amount):
                yield self._get_change_for_denomination(change, d, i)

    def denominations_less_than_or_equal_to(self, amount):
        '''Yields (index, denomination)'''
        return takewhile(lambda (i, d): d <= amount, enumerate(self.denominations))

    def _get_value_for_zero_change(self):
        abstractMethod()

    def _get_change_for_denomination(self, change, denomination, denomination_index):
        abstractMethod()

    def _value_to_store_for_amount(self, value):
        abstractMethod()


class AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger(CoinChanger):
        '''Given a set of denominations, yields all possible ways of making change for a given value.'''
    def __init__(self, denominations):
        super(AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger, self).__init__(denominations)

    def _get_value_for_zero_change(self):
        return tuple([0] * len(self.denominations))

    def _get_change_for_denomination(self, change, denomination, denomination_index):
        new_change = list(change)
        new_change[denomination_index] += 1
        return tuple(new_change)

    def _value_to_store_for_amount(self, value):
        return list(value)


class MinimumCoinChanger(CoinChanger):
        '''Given a set of denominations, a best way (minimize the number of coins) of making change for a given value.'''
    def __init__(self, denominations):
        super(MinimumCoinChanger, self).__init__(denominations)

    def _get_value_for_zero_change(self):
        return tuple([0] * len(self.denominations))

    def _get_change_for_denomination(self, change, denomination, denomination_index):
        new_change = list(change)
        new_change[denomination_index] += 1
        return tuple(new_change)

    def _value_to_store_for_amount(self, value):
        try:
            return [ min(value, key=sum) ]
        except ValueError:
            return []


class BooleanCoinChanger(CoinChanger):
        '''Given a set of denominations, determines whether it is possible to make change for a given value'''
        def __init__(self, denominations):
        super(BooleanCoinChanger, self).__init__(denominations)

    def _get_value_for_zero_change(self):
        return True

    def _get_change_for_denomination(self, change, denomination, denomination_index):
        assert change == True
        return change

    def _value_to_store_for_amount(self, value):
        for v in value:
            return [ True ]
        else:
            return []
```

---

## Test file: [change_test.py](https://github.com/jishi9/coin-change/blob/d4e14ef1e70ee68718dcdafe262ed57ee0293883/change_test.py)

```
from change import AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger, MinimumCoinChanger, BooleanCoinChanger
import unittest

class AllPossibilitiesCoinChangerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_change_for_zero(self):
        changer = AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger((1,3))
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 0, (0,0))

    def test_change_for_one(self):
        changer = AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger((1,3))
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 1, (1,0))

    def test_change_for_multiple(self):
        changer = AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger((1,3))
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 3, (3,0), (0,1))

    def test_change_for_many(self):
        changer = AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger((1,3,4))
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 6, (6,0,0), (3,1,0), (2,0,1), (0,2,0))

    def test_impossible_change(self):
        changer = AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger((3,5))
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 4)
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 2)

    def assertChangeForAmountIs(self, changer, amount, *values):
        actual_values = set(changer.change_for(amount))
        unordered_values = set(values)
        self.assertEquals(unordered_values, actual_values)
        self.assertEquals(len(values), len(unordered_values))


class MinimumCoinChangerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_change_for_zero(self):
        changer = MinimumCoinChanger((1,3))
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 0, (0,0))

    def test_change_for_one(self):
        changer = MinimumCoinChanger((1,3))
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 1, (1,0))

    def test_change_for_multiple(self):
        changer = MinimumCoinChanger((1,3))
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 3, (0,1))

    def test_change_for_many(self):
        changer = MinimumCoinChanger((1,3,4))
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, 6, (0,2,0))

    def test_impossible_change(self):
        changer = MinimumCoinChanger((3,5))
        self.assertNotChangeable(changer, 4)
        self.assertNotChangeable(changer, 2)

    def assertChangeForAmountIs(self, changer, amount, change):
        actual_change = list(changer.change_for(amount))
        self.assertEquals([change], actual_change)

    def assertNotChangeable(self, changer, amount):
        self.assertEquals([], list(changer.change_for(amount)))


class BooleanCoinChangerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_change_for_zero(self):
        changer = BooleanCoinChanger((1,3))
        self.assertChangeable(changer, 0)

    def test_change_for_one(self):
        changer = BooleanCoinChanger((1,3))
        self.assertChangeable(changer, 1)

    def test_change_for_multiple(self):
        changer = BooleanCoinChanger((1,3))
        self.assertChangeable(changer, 3)

    def test_change_for_many(self):
        changer = BooleanCoinChanger((1,3,4))
        self.assertChangeable(changer, 6)

    def test_impossible_change(self):
        changer = BooleanCoinChanger((3,5))
        self.assertNotChangeable(changer, 4)
        self.assertNotChangeable(changer, 2)

    def assertChangeForAmountIs(self, changer, amount, expected_change):
        actual_change = list(changer.change_for(amount))
        self.assertEquals(expected_change, actual_change)

    def assertChangeable(self, changer, amount):
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, amount, [True])

    def assertNotChangeable(self, changer, amount):
        self.assertChangeForAmountIs(changer, amount, [])
```

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. Stop writing classes

The title for this section comes from [Jack Diederich's PyCon 2012 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

A *class* represents a group of *objects* with similar behaviour, and an *object* represents some kind of persistent *thing*. So when deciding what classes a program is going to need, the first question to ask is, "what kind of persistent things does this program need to represent?"

In this case the persistent things are:

1. collections of denominations of coins (represented by lists of numbers); and
2. caches of previously computed results (represented by dictionaries).

There does not seem to be a need for any other class of object.

#### 2. Other review comments

1. If you limited all lines to a maximum of 79 characters, as recommended by the [Python style guide (PEP8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length), we wouldn't have to scroll horizontally to read it here.
2. Trying to run the code in the post, I get `IndentationError`. Possibly a copy-paste problem?
3. There are docstrings for the classes but they do not explain how to use them. How do I construct instances of these classes? What methods may I call?
4. This assertion is too strong:

   ```
   assert all(type(d) == int for d in denominations)
   ```

   The change-making algorithm works with other kinds of numbers than `int`, for example it works just fine with [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html). See §5 below.
5. There are, in general, a very large number of ways of making change. So in the case of `AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger`, it's not a good idea to try to return them all as a list: this will soon fill the available memory. A better strategy is to *generate* the results one by one, to keep the memory usage bounded.
6. For the same reason, it makes no sense to try to cache the results of  `AllPossibilitiesCoinChanger`: this will fill the available memory. Caching these results doesn't even improve the runtime complexity: copying them out of the cache is no faster (asymptotically speaking) than generating them again.

#### 3. Separation of concerns

The logic for maintaining a cache of previously computed results (that is, for [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)) is mixed in with the logic for change-making. It would be better to [separate these concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) for clarity, maintainability, and reuse.

Memoization is most elegantly done using a [*decorator*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/), for example [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

#### 4. Revised implementation

Instead of classes, write functions!

```
from functools import lru_cache

def partitions(n, values):
    """Generate the ways of expressing n as a sum of items from the tuple
    values (with repetition, ignoring order).

    >>> list(partitions(6, (1, 2, 5)))
    [(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 5), (2, 2, 2)]

    """
    if n == 0:
        yield ()
    elif not values:
        return
    else:
        first = values[0]
        if first <= n:
            for p in partitions(n - first, values):
                yield (first,) + p
        yield from partitions(n, values[1:])

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def count_partitions(n, values):
    """Return the number of ways of expressing n as a sum of items from
    the tuple values (with repetition, ignoring order).

    >>> # Partition numbers: https://oeis.org/A000041
    >>> [count_partitions(i, tuple(range(1, 16))) for i in range(16)]
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 22, 30, 42, 56, 77, 101, 135, 176]

    """
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif not values:
        return 0
    else:
        first = values[0]
        count = count_partitions(n, values[1:])
        if first <= n:
            count += count_partitions(n - first, values)
        return count

def partitionable(n, values):
    """Return True if it is possible to express n as a sum of items from
    the tuple values (with repetition).

    >>> partitionable(11, (4, 5))
    False
    >>> partitionable(59, (6, 7))
    True

    """
    return any(True for _ in partitions(n, values))
```

Notes:

1. The docstrings contain *doctests*, small code examples that double as tests. These are runnable using the [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) module.
2. I've omitted `minimum_partitions`, but it should be clear from the above how I would write it.
3. The similarities in the code for `partitions` and `count_partitions` makes it tempting to try to combine them into a single algorithm. But this is hopeless, because `partitions` is a *generator* that is not memoized (as discussed in §2.6 above), whereas `count_partitions` is an ordinary function that *is* memoized. Even if we changed `partitions` to return a list, these functions are so simple that there would be as many differences as there are similarities, so that trying to combine them would just result in a mess that was hard to understand and maintain.

#### 5. Fractions

Here's an example to show why you might not want to insist that the values are `int`s:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> list(partitions(1, tuple(Fraction(1, i) for i in range(2, 5))))
[(Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 2)),
 (Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(1, 4)),
 (Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(1, 3)),
 (Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(1, 4), Fraction(1, 4))]
```